# C# Calling base constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I've Google'd "calling base constructor", and I'm not getting the answers I need.

Here's the constructor I have;

```
public class defaultObject
{
    Vector2 position;
    float rotation;
    Texture2D texture;

    public defaultObject(Vector2 nPos, float nRotation, Texture2D nTexture)
    {
        position = nPos;
        rotation = nRotation;
        texture = nTexture;
    }
}
```

Now I have that in place, I want to inherit the constructor and all its workings.
This is what I'd expect to do;

```
public class Block : defaultObject
{
    // variables inherited from defaultObject
    public Block : defaultObject; //calls defaultObject constructor
}
```

Why can't I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it hiding an inherited member?

Because I bet the method in the base class is not marked `virtual`.

---

I see that you removed that part of the question. Well, I've answered it anyway now...

Comment: Just fixed that, merci.

Answer (score 6):

Use `: base()`:

```
public class Block : defaultObject
{
    // variables inherited from defaultObject
    public Block ()
        : base()
    {}
}
```

or with parameters:

```
public class Block : defaultObject
{
    // variables inherited from defaultObject
    public Block (Vector2 nPos, float nRotation, Texture2D nTexture)
        : base(nPos, nRotation, nTexture)
    {}
}
```

Comment: I tried using : base(), now it's complaining that ':' is an invalid token.

Comment: I missed the () on the parameterless constructor, try adding those.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple problems in your code. It should be like this

```
public Block(Vector2 nPos, float nRotation, Texture2D nTexture) : base(nPos,nRotation,nTexture) // see the way params are passed to the base constructor
{}
```

Comment: Are you all just saying "param1" just to be quick?

Comment: yes.I have updated my answer to remove the confusion.

Comment: In your solution, I will have to end up typing all the constructor values when the base constructor does that already. Isn't there simpler way to refer the program to the base constructor?

Comment: you can call a parameter less constructor as well

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this and it seems happy, but now the object isn't being drawn in XNA.

Answer (score 0):

To call the base class's constructor:

```
public class Block : defaultObject
{
    // variables inherited from defaultObject
    public Block(npos, rotation, texture) : base(npos, rotation, texture); //calls defaultObject constructor
}
```

To override the update method, you must declare it virtual in the base class:

```
public virtual void update() { .. }
```

Comment: You're missing the types for the parameters to `Block(...)`.

Comment: Isn't there a quicker way? I end up writing the same constructor all over again even though I don't want to change it.